# Image location does not change in response to key events

Tags: java

```
package testapplication;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestApplication extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    int sizex = 800;
    int sizey = 650;
    int x, y, xDirection, yDirection;
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;
    Image character;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){

                move();

                Thread.sleep(5);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR!!!");
        }
    }

    public void move(){
        x += xDirection;
        y += yDirection;
        if(x <= 0)
            x = 0;
        if(x >= 778)
            x = 778;
        if(y <= 22)
            y = 22;
        if(y >= 628)
            y = 628;
    }

    public void setXDirection(int xdir){
        xDirection = xdir;

    }
    public void setYDirection(int ydir){
        yDirection = ydir;
    }

    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30);

    public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

            //Key press inputs "WASD"
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                setYDirection(-1);
            }
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                setXDirection(-1);
            }
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                setYDirection(+1);
            }
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                setXDirection(+1);
            }
            //end Key press inputs "WASD"

        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            //Key release inputs "WASD"
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                setYDirection(0);
            }
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                setXDirection(0);
            }
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                setYDirection(0);
            }
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                setXDirection(0);
            }
            //end Key release inputs "WASD"

        }
    }


    public TestApplication() {
        //Load images
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Min/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestApplication/src/testapplication/Untitled-1.png") {};
        character = i.getImage();
        //Game properties
        addKeyListener(new AL());
        setTitle("TestApplication");
        setSize(sizex, sizey);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        x = 30;
        y = 628;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("Welcome to TESTTEST", 300,125);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawImage(character, x, y, this);


        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestApplication ta = new TestApplication();
        //Threads
        Thread t1 = new Thread();
        t1.start();
    }

}
```

In my Java code, there is supposed to be an image that moves using the WASD keys. The image shows, yet it will not move. What's wrong?
This is a simple Java code that is supposed to make an image roam around the window with WASD keys. I am not sure what I did wrong in the code, I've double checked and everything looked fine...

Comment: Have you run this in an IDE debugger and traced through the code to see what is happening? That is the place to start (you may have to simulate keypresses)

Comment: How do I run the IDE debugger (I am actually a little new to this, to be honest)

**EDIT** _The debugger didn't really help, considering it only opened the window and the same thing happened_

Comment: Blaze - The documentation for your IDE will explain that.  As will your friend Mr Google, if you ask him politely about "*<insert-name-of-your-ide>* debug tutorial" .... or something like that.

Comment: Before you can make progress you are going to have to take a detour and do some studying and self-education.  If your question pertains to a high school or college class, use the resources available at the school.  If you're doing this by yourself, read the documentation for the IDE you're using and start with simple programs to learn how the debugger lets you step through your code one statement at a time.

Comment: Use key bindings.... please

Comment: The point is that we could debug your program for you and tell you what the fix is ... but that won't help you solve the next problem, and the next one and so on.

Comment: Never call `repaint()` from a painting method.  A call to repaint will trigger another call to paint, so you'll be painting in an infinite loop.  This isn't the cause of your issue, but it is something that's important to know.

Comment: Also note  `Thread t1 = new Thread(); t1.start();` You are creating a thread with a default `run()` method that does nothing but exit immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you need to change the image location while the user presses one of the wsda keys then you need to add 1 and -1 to the current value of x and y ( image location).  You just set 1 and -1 which will move the image just one pixel even if, for example, you press the d button multiple times over and over.

You need to change method setXDirection to this (I have added a plus before the equal sign to add xDir value to whatever xDirection is.)

```
public void setXDirection(int xDir)
{
     xDirection += xDir
}
```

Make the same correction with yDirection (yDirection += yDir)

Second, you don't call your paint method.  You have to call it each time your user presses a key (one of wasd ofcourse), so do it at the final line of your keyReleased method.

I hope these two correct your code but I think you need to recheck the code again with much care.

Good luck,

Iman

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the `Runnable` instance to the `Thread` constructor.

Your main method should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestApplication ta = new TestApplication();
    //Threads
    Thread t1 = new Thread(ta);
    t1.start();
}
```